# how to use async-await in custom validators

Tags: express

i have this array of validation rules for password changes, but there is an error says:

> "'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules."

```
const validationRules = [
  body('current_password')
    .exists()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('current password is required')
    .custom((value, { req }) => {
      const { id } = req.user;
      const { current_password } = req.body;

      const detailUser = await User.where('id', id).fetch({
        withRelated: ['roles'],
      });

      if (!detailUser) {
        throw new Error('User not found');
      }

      if (
        !bcrypt.compareSync(current_password, detailUser.attributes.password)
      ) {
        const errorMessage =
          'Current password you entered did not match our records';
        Logger.error(errorMessage);
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
      }

      return true;
    }),
  body('new_password')
    .exists()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('New password is required'),
  body('confirm_password')
    .exists()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .custom((value, { req }) => {
      if (value !== req.body.new_password) {
        throw new Error('Password confirmation does not match password');
      }
      return true;
    }),
];
```

where should i put async to fix this error, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: async functions must return a resolved or rejected Promise because truthy or falsy values won't stop the chain ([#1028](https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/1028#issuecomment-830561518)).

**Source**: [Custom validator chain](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#customvalidator)

So, you need to reject to use error message and use `async` at the custom `function(){}`

Making those changes to your code,

```
const validationRules = [
  body('current_password')
    .exists()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('current password is required')
    .custom(async (value, { req }) => {
      const { id } = req.user;
      const { current_password } = req.body;

      const detailUser = await User.where('id', id).fetch({
        withRelated: ['roles'],
      });

      if (!detailUser) {
        return Promise.reject('User not found');
      }

      if (
        !bcrypt.compareSync(current_password, detailUser.attributes.password)
      ) {
        const errorMessage =
          'Current password you entered did not match our records';
        Logger.error(errorMessage);
        return Promise.reject(errorMessage);
      }

      return Promise.resolve();
    }),
  body('new_password')
    .exists()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .withMessage('New password is required'),
  body('confirm_password')
    .exists()
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
    .custom(async (value, { req }) => {
      if (value !== req.body.new_password) {
        return Promise.reject('Password confirmation does not match password');
      }
      
      return Promise.resolve();
    }),
];
```